# Fixed element without predefined width initially put in bootstrap container does not inherit width from parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with sticky functionality, making element stay at the top when scrolling. It is a `div` inside bootstrap fluid container.
Alas, as soon as it becomes fixed it gets its width defined by children (label and text input).

`width: inherit` has no effect.

What magic do I need for making `width` the same it would be if element was static.

Comment: @thepio Tried it, but then it ignores right margin of the body.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed elements are positioned relative to the `body`, so setting `inherit` will not do anything, unless there is `width` on `body`. Only way to make it relative to another element is to using `js`.

Comment: I have only an idea how to to it once, but ideal responsive solution requires detecting width changes of 'parent' element.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment you could do it like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  right: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="fixed"></div>
</body>
```

So basically you just set the `left` and `right` values to the same value as your body margin on the left and right sides.

Comment: I made a mistake. Bootstrap centers the content and changes margins dynamically depending on visual breakpoints. So hardcoding is not a good idea...at least if not inside media queries with same breakpoints as bootstrap has.